Stepper custom view below image in flutter
How can I achieve something as shown in this screenshot in flutter?
I need to get some clarity for the UI development
:
I want to achieve this UI design regarding updated above link and give me a stepper custom code for same UI design and give me a clear explanation for this UI.

This Stepper can be made using the existing widgets like Row , Column and Container. I have added a sample code which gives the output you want , you can make your changes according to your need.
Full Code : -
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 List title = ['Title 1','Title 2','Title 3','Title 4','Title 5'];
  List label = ['Label 1','Label 2','Label 3','Label 4','Label 5'];
 List body = ['Body 1','Body 2','Body 3','Body 4','Body 5'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                for(int i =0;i < title.length;i++)...[
                SizedBox(
                height: 120,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    if(i%2==0)...[
                    Column(
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                          Text(title[i],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                         const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Container(
                           width: 150,
                          decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
                                    
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight:  Radius.circular(15),bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
                            border:
                            Border(
                              left: BorderSide(color: Colors.white,width: 0.1),
                                    right: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          child:  Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                
                            children: [Text(label[i],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                           
                            Text(body[i],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),]
                    else...[Container(
                           width: 150,)],const SizedBox(width: 10,),Column(children: [
                  Container(
                  
                    height: 7.5,width: 7.5,decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.white
                  ),)
                  ,Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      
                      width: 2.5,
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                 
                ],),
                if(i%2!=0)...[
                    const SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Column(
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                          Text(title[i],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                         const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Container(
                           width: 200,
                          decoration:   BoxDecoration(
                                    
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            border:
             Border.all(color: Colors.white)
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          child:  Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                
                            children: [Text(label[i],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                           
                            Text(body[i],style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),]
                  ],
                ),
              ),]
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} 

Output : -

